# XMLHttpRequest CROS issues when uploading(post) files to S3 from browser and redirecting to a custom url

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, cross-domain, laravel-5.1

This case is easy to understand, and I have paste enough information about the problem. Thank you for your patience. :)

There is a case that I use `JQuery File Upload (UI)` to upload images to AWS S3 directly from client browser, here is the post data:
    AWSAccessKeyId: xxxxxx,
    key: filename.jpg,
    Policy: xxxxxx,
    Signature: xxxxx,
    acl: 'private',
    success_action_redirect:'http://example.org/test',
    'Content-Type': x.type
the policy and signature are totally fine, and the image has been uploaded as well.

but there is problem when redirect to the pre-defined url `http://example.org/test`:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/. 
The request was redirected to 'http://localhost:8000/test?bucket=mybucket&key=filename.jpg&etag=xxxxxxxx', 
which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

I paste the http request and response for `https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/`:

Request:

```
POST /mybucket/ HTTP/1.1
Host: s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 298856
Origin: http://localhost:8000
X-CSRF-TOKEN: H5HRwmtwCVAxIgmAvM8YL5bgayuDyyQV2UKUqnhT
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryhI9Z5605GrykYXvT
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="xxxxxxx"
Referer: http://localhost:8000/xxxxxxxx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
x-amz-id-2: g1VdA6dwEHl+y/C8nSTD7qzxL7gX9o3c0JV7Cj7cKYDeUPNvlrkRzaJEz4PtNFCPZhOAhA8pqzw=
x-amz-request-id: 48C7F5DB54CCEF65
Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2015 02:35:31 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
ETag: "772d776abbc1bb619d208c92d4b986c9"
Location: http://localhost:8000/test?bucket=mybucket&key=filename.jpg&etag=xxxxxxxx
Content-Length: 0
Server: AmazonS3
```

And for the redirect endpoint `http://example.org/test`, which is implemented in Laravel 5.1. Here are the relative routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'test'], function () {
    Route::options('/', function(){
        return response(null, 204)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type')
            ->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '1728000')
            ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain charset=UTF-8')
            ->header('Content-Length', '0');
    });
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return response('test', 200)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type');
    });

});
```

When `GET` `http://example.org/test` directly, here is the HTTP response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 29 Oct 2015 02:47:51 GMT
Host:localhost:8000
```

Any body can help me figure out where is the problem? Thanks!